# Origin Thin Setup fails on windows 10 fresh install

Tags: windows-10, gaming

Trying to install origin thin setup on a fresh windows 10 install. I got theses errors:

**The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP140.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.**

[image]

**The code execution cannot proceed because VCRUNTIME140.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR:** Some pre-requisites are missing from origin thing setup. Download+install this https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x86.exe

Long answer:
First and foremost, don't follow any youtube videos that tell you to download files from shady websites. Those files could damage your computer or compromise your data and privacy.

To fix those errors simply download and install Microsoft Visual C++ for Visual Studio 2019 from the official Microsoft site:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/downloads/

Select the x86 version

[image]

Direct link:

https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x86.exe

Comment: I would charge your answer to simply say, prerequisite software is missing. Download and install the C++ resist and continue the origin install.

Comment: What exactly is origin?

Comment: @Ramhound *"What exactly is origin?"* - OP is referring to the [Origin gaming client from EA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_(service)), which is similar to Steam. `OriginThinSetup.exe` appears to be the name of the web installer for Origin on Windows.

Comment: @Anaksunaman - That definitely was not clear.

Comment: @spikey_richie I've added your suggestion, thanks